# Matrix Equation with factoring

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I've been working through some practice problems for my upcoming linear algebra exam and have a matrix equation that has me questioning properties of matrix equations.

**Problem:**

Given the two matrices 
A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} 
and
B = \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\3&4\end{bmatrix}, 
find the solution X to the matrix equation 3(*A* - *B* + *X*) = *AX* + *B*.

**My Attempt:**

Carry out the *A - B* to create a new matrix *C*, then we are left with

3(*C* + *X*) = *AX* + *B*.

Distribute the 3 so now we have

3C + 3X = AX + B

Swap the terms to the correct sides

3X - AX = B - 3C

Pull out the X

(A + 3)X = B - 3C

Then this is where things get fuzzy. My gut instinct is to do

X = $(A+3)^-1$(B - 3C)

but how would that work with the 3? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have $AX,$ then you say to pull out the $X.$ The bad news is that you then put $XA,$ which need not be the same. It would be alright as $(A+3I)X$

Comment: the way you have edited it now, $3X-AX$ should become $(3I-A)X$

Answer (score 0):

The number 3 can be represented as the matrix with 3s down the middle. However be careful, there is a mistake in your algebra, when you swapped terms around, AX should have become negative.

Comment: "$AX$ should have become negative" is improper (a matrix is not negative...) ; you should say for example "$AX$ is changed into $-AX$". Moreover, there is another mistake, it is the assumed commutativity $AX \to XA$...

Comment: How would the number 3 be represented in a 2 x 2 seeing as those are both the construction of A and B?

Comment: Like $\begin{pmatrix}3&0\\0&3 \end{pmatrix}$.